# The below program is not running correctly

Tags: arrays, loops, clang, do-while

The Program is to simply iterate through a character array and fill up another 2D character array with values from the initial Array. But the program while running is not showing any output and the console is simply waiting.

Could Someone help me with this. I know this should be simple but I'm missing it!

```c
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char arr1[26][26]={{""}};
    char arr[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {    
        int j=i;
        do
        {
            arr1[i][j]=arr[j];
            j=(i+1)%26;
        }
        while(j!=i);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        printf("{ ");
        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            printf("%c, ",arr1[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" }\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some debugging to your application. It seems the `do...while` loop always has just 1 iteration?

Comment: @Luuk I am incrementing the J value inside the Do-While loop as '''j=(i+1)%26;'''

Comment: your while loops forever

Answer (score 0):

The way you're initializing the `arr1` 2D character array with `{{""}}` **is not correct for character arrays**, you should leave it empty or initialize it with a default character like a space `' '`.

And you have a **loop condition issue in the inner loop**, you're using a `do-while` loop that sets `j` to `(i+1)%26`. This means the loop will always run at least once, but you might want to use a regular `while` loop with a different condition to properly fill the 2D array.

Try this way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char arr1[26][26];
    char arr[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {    
        int j = i;
        while (arr[j] != '\0') {
            arr1[i][j] = arr[j];
            j = (j + 1) % 26;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("{ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            printf("%c, ", arr1[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" }\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```